# SetNamedSecurityInfo execution restarts system

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to change audit settings of a folder.As i was testing my code on different machines   i found that SetNamedSecurityInfo call restarts the system.This happened with some machines.A pop up generates which says "**Windows has encountered a security issue and will restart in one minute**".I'm not able to figure out the reason.Any help will be appreciated!

```
HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
HANDLE hToken;
DWORD val;
BOOL result;
result = OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken);
if (result == 0)
{
    printf("\nBreak After open process");   
    return 0;
}
else{
    printf("\ncontinue after open process");
}
// Used for reading SACL's
result = SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_SECURITY_NAME, TRUE);
if (result == 0)
{
    printf("\nBreak After setprivilege");   
    return 0;
}
else{
    printf("\ncontinue after open process");
}
CloseHandle(hToken);
retval = GetNamedSecurityInfo(file, SE_FILE_OBJECT, SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, &owner, NULL, NULL, &sacl, &psd);
if(retval != 0)
{
     wcout << "GetNamedSecurityInfo failed with error: " << retval << endl;
     return -1;
}
printf("\nBuilt trust successfully before");
BuildTrusteeWithSid(ptrust,psd);
printf("\nBuilt trust successfully");


printf("\ntrying to modify ...");
EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;
PACL pNewSACL = NULL;
ACCESS_MODE AccessMode =  SET_AUDIT_SUCCESS; //SET_AUDIT_SUCCESS, SET_AUDIT_FAILURE
DWORD dwAccessRights = 0X410D0060;
DWORD dwInheritance = CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE | OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE;
ZeroMemory(&ea, sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));

ea.grfAccessPermissions = dwAccessRights;
ea.grfAccessMode = SET_AUDIT_SUCCESS;
ea.grfInheritance = dwInheritance;
ea.Trustee = *(ptrust); 



DWORD dwRes = SetEntriesInAcl(1, &ea, sacl, &pNewSACL);
if(dwRes != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("SetEntriesInAcl() error %u\n", dwRes);
}
else
{
    printf("SetEntriesInAcl() is OK\n");
}

dwRes = SetNamedSecurityInfo(file, SE_FILE_OBJECT, SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, NULL, pNewSACL);
if(dwRes != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("SetNamedSecurityInfo() error %u\n", dwRes);

}
else
    printf("SetNamedSecurityInfo() is OK\n\n");


LocalFree(psd);
```

Comment: Interesting! Give more infos and code.

Comment: Maybe instead of printf you could write to file and flush immediately. That way you know what was the  last action done before it crashed.

Comment: its crashing as soon as setnamedsecurityinfo gets executed.

Comment: What context is your code running in?  Is it just a normal executable being run by an interactive user, or is it something special?

Comment: its a normal executable with privilege SE_SECURITY_NAME given to its process.

Comment: What file or folder are you trying to manipulate? Also to get that right: that's a popup and the shutdown is an orderly shutdown. It's not a bluescreen and subsequent restart?

Answer (score 0):

There is an global policy entry that controls the shutdown if the system was unable to log security audits.

See:
"Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Local Policies\Security Options"
"Audit: Shut down system immediately if unable to log security audits"

This could happen in combination with:

"Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Local Policies\Security Options"
"Audit: Audit the accesss of global system objects"

Comment: yes i see it but its disabled on all the systems.I think its not the issue because for me reboot is happening while setting audit ace for a directory object not while generating logs.

Comment: The log is automatically generated if audit access of objects is activated. There are certainly various other policy settings that may be involved.